# How to get IndexPath and UItableView on Swipe gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in which I have added `UISwipeGesture` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIndetifier];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gestureR;
gestureR = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom)];
gestureR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:gestureR];
  return cell;
}
```

My selector is responding on swipe.

Now I want to manipulate the cell based on the `SwipeGesture`. But I am not able to get the `indexPath` and `UITableView`. How can I get these to manipulate the cell. Or is their any other way to do so.

Please assist me.

Comment: show code of Swipe Gesture Selector that you have tried.

Comment: I have only declared the mehtod to check the working of gesture..I dont know how to access the indexPath @HardikShekhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below..

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gestureR;
gestureR = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
gestureR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:gestureR];


-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UIGestureRecognizer *)tap{
    CGPoint touch           = [tap locationInView:yourtableview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath  = [yourtableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:touch];
    CustomCell *cell      = [yourtableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Let me know it is working or not.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Yes it works..Thanx for quick response. Please also tell me how can I select the swiped cell programatically

Comment: Do you want to get swiped cell in handleSwipeFrom method ?

Comment: Yes.. I want to perform didSelect in handleSwipeFrom:

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 //Modify yourCode
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gestureR;
gestureR = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];


-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
CGPoint center= sender.view.center;
CGPoint point = [sender.view.superview convertPoint:center toView:tableViewObj];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableViewObj indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add tag in swipe gesture view and you can access the tag in handleSwipeFrom method as

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gestureR;
    gestureR = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom)];
    gestureR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
   [cell setTag:indexPath.row]; //set tag value
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:gestureR];


- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"tabbed!!");
    NSLog(@"%d", sender.view.tag);    //here you will get the index path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.appcoda.com/swipeable-uitableviewcell-tutorial/

I think this is what you are looking for.